Facing issue while trying to read collection from firestore using Firebase Kotlin SDK
I am facing ClassNotFoundException while reading collection. I have added all the needed dependencies in gradle file. I did the sign in process with custom token.
Exception I am getting is mentioned below -
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dev.gitlive.firebase.DecodersKt"

Here is the shared module gradle dependencies
val commonMain by getting { 
    dependencies { 
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core) 
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.core) 
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation) 
    implementation(libs.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json) 
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.logging) 
    implementation(libs.koin.core) 
    implementation(libs.sql.coroutines.extensions) 
    implementation(libs.firebase.firestore)
    implementation(libs.firebase.common)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json) 
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth) }
    }


These are android module denpencies.
dependencies {
implementation(projects.shared) 
implementation(libs.compose.ui) 
implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
implementation(libs.compose.material3) 
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose) 
implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat) 
implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout) 
implementation(libs.material) 
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx) 
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx) 
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx) 
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx) 
debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling) 
implementation(libs.koin.android) 
implementation(platform(libs.google.firebase.bom)) 
implementation(libs.firebase.common.ktx) 
implementation(libs.google.firebase.common) 
}

Below are lines of code I am trying to read collection after calling signInWithCustomToken() -
tokenResponse = auth.signInWithCustomToken(customtoken)
val response = firestore.collection("collectionPath")
.document("documentPath").get().data(MyDataClass.serializer())
println("response... $response")

//Exception
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dev.gitlive.firebase.DecodersKt"



Please suggest if anyone faced this issue or some workaround to fix this issue.
Here is the library link -
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/gitliveapp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/

Based on what I'm seeing, you should only be accessing dev.gitlive.firebase.internal.decode unless you're using a much older version of the dependency.  That dev.gitlive.firebase.DecodersKt file hasn't been in place since version 1.   Their SDK is on version 2.1.0 right now.
Is your dependency version up-to-date?
